# .loc The same column at once with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

This might be a rather useless question but I would like to learn how to do
.loc for same column sliced by rows at same time. Lets imagine I have this df:

```
k1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4])
k2 = pd.DataFrame( [5,6,7,8])
k3 =  pd.DataFrame([9,10,11,12])
frames = [k1,k2,k3]
k4 = pd.concat(frames, axis = 1).T
k4.loc[1] = 'HOla'
k4.loc[2] = 'Bye'
k4 = k4.reset_index()
k4.loc[0,4]= 0.00
k4.loc[1:2,4]= 288
k4.loc[3:,4]= 'New'
```

How could I update column 4 with just 1 sentence, or is it impossible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why cant you do this?                                                                             k4.loc[:,4]=[0,299,299,'New1','New1']

Comment: Sorry, I haven't read your comment. I can't do this because it is a dataframe with dimension 300, I can't use a list with 120 different  elements (many of them are repeated). But thanks anyway

Comment: What I wanted to do is this:  k4.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3]] = 'NEIN'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `:` for select all rows:

```
#if need update column 4 to value 1
k4.loc[:, 4] = 1
#if need update column 3 to value a
k4.loc[:, 3] = 'a'
#for select row : can be omit
#if need update row 3 to value b
k4.loc[3] = 'b'
#if need update row 2 to value c
k4.loc[2, :] = 'c'
print (k4)
  index    0    1    2  3            4
0     0    1    2    3  a            1
1     0    5    6    7  a  some string
2     c    c    c    c  c            c
3     b    b    b    b  b            b
4     2  Bye  Bye  Bye  a            1
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but I was asking about the possibility of doing the updates of the columns in on sentence, not by using .loc 3 times.

Comment: I dont understand, what is desired output?

Comment: No, dont worry. It are 4 samples only. ;)

Comment: The same as I get, but not by doing .loc[a:b], then .loc[b:c] and then .loc[c:d]. I wanted to know if it does exists something like .loc[a:b]  = 1 & .loc[b:c] = 2 & ...

Comment: No, it doesnt exist in pandas. If need update multiple you need  multiple loc

Comment: Ok, understood. Thanks!!

Comment: I think I was looking for this, mate:   k4.iloc[:,[0,1,2,3]] = 'NEIN'